# Changing the size of a jquery UI dialog dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a jquery dialog . I am displaying an asp.net gridview within the dialog.
I want the size of the dialog to change based on the size of the grid view.

There is a button, which shows the dialog when its clicked.

I want to set the size of the dialog such that the gridview fits in it perfectly.

```
   I have my javascript code below : 



 $("#ViewModalPopup").dialog({
                height: 800px,
                scrollable: true,
                width: 800,
                modal: true

            });
```

Here #ViewModalPopup is the div that encloses the modal popup.

I tried implementing the following logic to adjust the height of the dialog based on the size of the div :

```
var maxHeight = 600;
            var currentHeight = $('#ViewModalPopup').height();

if (currentHeight < maxHeight) {
                var desiredHeight = currentHeight
                }
            else
            {
                var desiredHeight = maxHeight;
                }

  $("#ViewModalPopup").dialog({
                    height: desiredheight,
                    scrollable: true,
                    width: 800,
                    modal: true

                });
```

But it is not working as

```
var currentHeight = $('#ViewModalPopup').height();
```

is coming out to be null from the second button click onwards.

Is there any way I can change the size of the dialog dynamically ?

Comment: What happens when you don't set a height at all?

Comment: Hi Jason P ! Sometimes the gridview has so many rows that it stretches from the top to the bottom of the screen. Setting a height and putting a scrollbar helps in limiting the height of the dialog.

Comment: So you basically want a max height. Have you tried setting the `max-height` on your dialog div using css?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set like

```
 $("#ViewModalPopupDiv1").dialog("option", "maxHeight", 600);
```

[**API**](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-maxWidth)

Comment: Hey Thanks ! $("#ViewModalPopupDiv1").dialog("option", "maxHeight", 600); was actually what I was looking for . Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: ***maxheight*** and not ***height*** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* set dynamic height of modal popup and scroll according to window height */
function setModalMaxHeight(element) {
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.$content = this.$element.find('.modal-content');
    var borderWidth = this.$content.outerHeight() - this.$content.innerHeight();
    var dialogMargin = $(window).width() < 768 ? 20 : 60;
    var contentHeight = $(window).height() - (dialogMargin + borderWidth);
    var headerHeight = this.$element.find('.modal-header').outerHeight() || 0;
    var footerHeight = this.$element.find('.modal-footer').outerHeight() || 0;
    var maxHeight = contentHeight - (headerHeight + footerHeight);

    this.$content.css({
        'overflow': 'hidden'
    });

    this.$element.find('.modal-body').css({
        'max-height': maxHeight,
        'overflow-y': 'auto'
    });
}
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).show();
    setModalMaxHeight(this);
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($('.modal.in').length != 0) {
        setModalMaxHeight($('.modal.in'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Add some description